# How can i change the textview of a layout in different activity on click of customInfoWindow in main activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, textview

So, what my code is right now that I have a on click custom info.
I have specific custom windows for specific places using this code:

**Main Java Activity:**

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        if("India".equals(marker.getTitle())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,India.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if("Australia".equals(marker.getTitle())){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Australia.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

This is currently what I have.

The only difference between the 2 layouts is the text.

Is there some code which I could write that when customInfowWindow of Sydney marker is clicked the text of the the layout changes to what i want for Sydney and when someone clicks on the custominfowindow of India the text changes in that layout to what I want for India.

For example, When someone clicks on infowidow of any 2 nations I want them to get their respective information not by making different layout but by changetext command.

Also this is not my full code I only gave the code which could be changed or Is useful.

Please give the direct answer.

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you have different classes for each country activity but all these activities has the same layout? If it is your design, you can send something in the `Intent`, for example, the text to show in function of country selected, and process it in `onCreate` of each activity.

Comment: Yes i have different classes which i dont want to.Could you please explain how to do it I am very new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the selected title to next activity using `putExtra` and get the title on next Activity using `getExtra` using intent and change textview based on the selected title.

**Send using -**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,India.class);
intent.putExtra("title",marker.getTitle())
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receive Using -**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
    //Find id of your text views
    ...
    ....
    String title  = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    textView1.setText(title);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: May I know where are those textview 1 and textview 2 defined I assume in India.class and Australia.class?

Comment: @AtmosphericProductions You only need to write the "Receive Using" code in your `onCreate` of each country activity, to obtain in `title` variable the text setted in `onInfoWindowClick` in the `Intent`. Then you need to obtain the reference to the `TextView` (with `findViewByID`), and set the `title` text: `yourTextView.setText( title);`

Comment: You can set the title which you got using getStringExtra to  those textview 1 and textview 2 according to your need. try to get on onCreate method of activity.

Comment: @AtmosphericProductions I have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a common activity to display info of any country.
For example name it InfoDisplayer. Then you should edit your method like below.

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoDisplayer.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (marker.getTitle()){
        case "India":
            bundle.putString("info", "India info");
            //you can put any info String, Int, e.g
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case "Australia":
            bundle.putString("info", "Australia info");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the info from InfoDisplayer.class onCreate() method like

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String info = bundle.getString("info");
```

So you can use that string wherever you want

Comment: How can i change the text in the string

Comment: Which string do you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

In your onInfoWindowClick function you need to set a parameter in the Intent you are going to use to start each country activity:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    if("India".equals(marker.getTitle())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,India.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",marker.getTitle())
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if("Australia".equals(marker.getTitle())){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Australia.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",marker.getTitle())
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In all country activity, in onCreate:

```
@Overrride
public void onCreate(....) {
    .....
    .....
    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

    TextView txTitle = findViewById( R.id.tittle_textview_identifier_in_your_activity_layout);
    txTitle.setText( title);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: How can I set the paramter if the textview is in allcountry layout? and how can I give something to the string in order to set text for txview 1 and textview 2

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your doubts. What is the error you have with this code?